# Replace custom markup in string with html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have strings/sentences that have special markup in them.  I need to replace them in the string with a button element in the same location.

My thinking was to use RegEx to find them and then use some JQuery to replace them; however haven't figured out the RegEx.  So not sure if this is a RegEx solution or perhaps a it is or a JQuery or RegEx/JQuery solution?  I have tried this RegEx but can't isolate each; which if I could perhaps use JavaScript replace (?) with my button, populating data attributes with stuff from the special markup...

```
<START.*<END>
```

For example:

```
<START:person>Johny<END> went to school and completed a college degree in <START:degree>Engineering<END>.
```

Should return the following...

```
<button data-start='person'>Johnny</button> went to school and completed a college degree in <button data-start='industry'>Engineering</button>.
```

Any help or pointer on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match whatever is between `<>`, split it by `:` , have a dictionary for values to replace and replace the words before and after `:`

```js
const dict = {
  START: 'button',
  END: '/button',
  degree: 'industry'
}

const str = `<START:person>Johny<END> went to school and completed a college degree in <START:degree>Engineering<END>.`

const result = str.replace(/<(.*?)>/g, match => {
  const [a, b] = match.split(':');
  return a.replace(/\w+/g, k => dict[k]) + 
         (b ? b.replace(/\w+/g, k => " data-start='" + ( dict[k] || k ) + "'") : '');
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: quick question. would it be possible to include a span tag inside the button like this <span class="badge">person</span>. So it looks like this: <button data-start='person'>Johny <span class="badge">person</span></button>

Comment: @Rob yes, you can, i'll update the answer later for that

Comment: just wondering if you had that solution for the badge in the button?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the injection of the span.badge in there.

```
    var result = decoded_string.replace(/<(.*?)>/g, match => {
       var [a, b] = match.split(':');
       return a.replace(/\w+/g, k => dict[k]) +   (b ? b.replace(/\w+/g, k => " data-start='" + ( dict[k] || k ) + "'") : '') + 
       (b ? b.replace(/\w+/g, k => "<span class='badge pull-right margin_left'>" + ( dict[k] || k ) + "</span") : '');
    });
```